# What does the word 「間すらない」 mean?

Tags: grammar, meaning

What does the word 「間すらない」 mean?

> へいの中{なか}にはいったとたん投{とう}石{せき}をかけるやられて　あの調{ちょう}子{し}だ！声{こえ}をかける**間{ま}すらない**のだ

Comment: 「かけるやられて」・・・？　「かけられて」ですかね・・・

Answer (score 3, accepted):

間すらない is 間 + すら + ない, where すら is a particle usually translating to "even", so 声をかける間**すら**ない means "hadn't **even** time to say anything".

Comment: For OP:  すら is roughly an "advanced"/literary form of も or さえ.